# Get Samid from Full Name. get-aduser -identity $DN with spaces

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set some variables. I have a Full Name to work with.

I am able to run this to get the DN:

```
        $DN= dsquery user -name $Name
```

Then this:

```
        $Samid= $DN | dsget user -samid
```

But the output looks like this

```
         PS C:\Windows\system32> $samid
         samid     
         bclinton  
         dsget succeeded
```

instead of 
           $Samid = Bclinton

This command fails because I think the $DN has a space but the variable shows it in quotes.

```
        PS C:\Windows\system32> $DN
       "CN=Bill Clinton,OU=Employees,OU=External,OU=XXX Accounts,DC=XXXX,DC=local"

        $Samid = get-aduser -identity $DN

        get-aduser : Cannot find an object with identity: '"CN=Bill Clinton,OU=Employees,OU=External,OU=XXX Accounts,DC=XXX,DC=local"'     under: 'DC=XXX,DC=local'.
        At line:1 char:11
        +  $Samid = get-aduser -identity $DN
        +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("CN=Bill Clinto...=XXX,DC=local":ADUser) [Get-                  ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId :    ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

When I type it all out it returns the correct info.

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $Samid = get-aduser -Identity "CN=Bill Clinton,OU=Employees,OU=External,OU=XXX Accounts,DC=XXX,DC=local"

    PS C:\Windows\system32> $samid

     DistinguishedName : CN=Bill Clinton,OU=Employees,OU=External,OU=Accounts,DC=XXX,DC=local
     Enabled           : True
     GivenName         : Bill
     Name              : Bill Clinton
     ObjectClass       : user
     ObjectGUID        : f4514c3c-4496-44b0-a0b7-25b32d52cd7b
     SamAccountName    : bclinton
     SID               : S-1-5-21-1129724065-2108094634-3465950418-8044
     Surname           : Clinton
     UserPrincipalName : bclinton@XXX.local

      PS C:\Windows\system32> $samid.SamAccountName
      bclinton
```

I have read tons of pages but none that I found talk about this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you just trying to get the DN? If you already know the name you could just use `get-aduser -filter {name -eq "Bill Clinton"}` from there you can select the DistinguishedName or SamAccountName

Comment: I was trying to get the samid from the full name.

Comment: Your way won't pass the space in the variable either.  C:\Windows\system32> $Name
     Bill Clinton

     PS C:\Windows\system32> get-aduser -filter [name -eq $name}
At line:1 char:35
+ get-aduser -filter [name -eq $name}
+                                   ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: You have typos in your statement. You didnt enclose Bill Clinton in quotes and you used two different types of brackets which is what caused the error.

Comment: I will make my comment into an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the name you can use filter to search for it with Get-AdUser

```
get-aduser -filter {name -eq "Bill Clinton"} | Select DistinguishedName,SamAccountName
```

Use the results as you see fit.

Or another example

```
(get-aduser -filter {name -eq "Matt Cameron"}).SamAccountName
mcameron
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PS C:\> $samid = get-aduser -filter { Name -eq "Bill Clinton" } |
  select-object -expandproperty SamAccountName
PS C:\> $samid
bclinton
```

Comment: This is what i was suggesting to OP. Only thing is what is the significance of adding the -expandproperty here? Is it user preference?

Comment: @Matt - for singleton properties the effect is same as `(object).PropertyName` but a bit more straightforward for new users.